# Having 2 or more Drawings Fails Sending Sheet as attachement in an Email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script that emails a sheet as PDF attachment.

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vEFaekUExbHy7ttVwIpVn98MgQOKFNsfIImd4andp5M/edit?usp=sharing)

This used to work fine up until a week or so back. Now I get the error:
**We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 66, file "FeedbackEmail")**. This line is:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAdd, subject, message, {attachments: [theBlob]});
```

The following observations were made during my troubleshooting process:

1. No Drawings and/or having just 1 drawing on the sheet works always fine. Having more than 1 drawing (Simple Button drawings) on the sheet causes the error to occur randomly
2. Having 3 or more drawings causes the error to occur 90% of the time. When moving around the drawings on the sheet ensuring they don't fall under the same column helps the script send the email but for that moment only. Re-trying to send after couple of minutes causes the error again.
3. Having Button drawings exceeding more than 4 always fails sending the email

I have tried troubleshooting this on

- Different Browsers
- Different network connections
- On separate computers (Win 7 OS, Chrome Browser)
- There were no Windows OS, Anti-Virus or related software updates that I can remember of

I fail to understand the reason for this. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

**The printed sheet:**

[image]

**SCRIPT:**

```
function fdbkEmail() {

  // Set the Active Spreadsheet
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the Sheet you want to email
  var sourcesheet = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Feedback");

  // Range to get (Does not work, Emails the entire sheet)
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:M54');

  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

  var data = sourcesheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // The email senders name is fetched to display in the end of the email body (Generally the PM's Name)
  var emailsendername = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("BackEnd!B2").getValue();

  // The name of the person who the feedback was for
  var feedbackreciever = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Feedback").getRange('D1').getValue();

  // Name of the Project to be defined
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Feedback").getRange('I1').getValue();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = 'Hi,' + '\n' + '\n Please find attached PDF document of the feedback provided to ' + feedbackreciever + '\n' + '\nRevert for any clarifications.' + '\n' + '\n' + '\nRegards!' + '\n' + emailsendername;

  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + ' | Feedback | ' + feedbackreciever;

  var backEndSheet = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("BackEnd");

  // Request for additional Recipient Email Address
  var addRecp = Browser.inputBox('Add Recipients?', 'Enter email addresses seperating each by a comma and followed by a space (, )', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (addRecp == "cancel") {
    return;
  }
  backEndSheet.getRange('F2').setValue(addRecp);

  var emailAdd = backEndSheet.getRange('F2').getValues().toString();

  // Google scripts can't export just one Sheet from a Spreadsheet
  // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet data range into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Temp Feedback"); // can give any name.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:M54").getValues();

  var sheet = sourcesheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  var destrange = sheet.getRange('A1:M54');
  destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  // Make PDF, currently called "Planning Poker Estimates"
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
  var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(subject + ".pdf");

  // Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

  // Send the freshly constructed email (This is the line Error Occurs) 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAdd, subject, message, {attachments: [theBlob]});

  //Show a Pop-Up message on Email Confirmation
  {
    Browser.msgBox('Email Sent', 'A PDF Copy of the Feedback has been sent successfully to : ' + emailAdd, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added the script in the question. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I mentioned the code line that errors out. It's just before where the script starts in the question.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. I tried up to 6 drawings, with the following code: `function testMail() {
  var thisDoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var theBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(thisDoc.getId()).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    Session.getEffectiveUser(),
    "test mail 6 drawings",
    "test body 6",
    { attachments: [theBlob]}
  );
}`

Comment: Alright, I tried and it again errors out. Let me rule out GMail settings if that can be a possible reason.

Comment: I still get the error. I have made a copy of the sheet that I can share. Maybe you can identify if it's spreadsheet specific issue or something else. The Sheet in question is 'Feedback' and A53 has the Send Email button that you can use to trigger the script. [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vEFaekUExbHy7ttVwIpVn98MgQOKFNsfIImd4andp5M/edit?usp=sharing)